# URL subdomain ==> IIS WebSite : adding or removing bindings causing application pool to recycle

Tags: url, iis, binding, subdomain

On our Web Servers, we have one site by version of our application.

So we have this structure :

V1
V2
V3

We bind our customers by his subdomain to his version. For example, bmo.ourapplication.app to V2

Our problem is when we are adding or removing a binding, our application stop and start (Application Pool Recycling).

In this example, when we add bmo.ourapplication.app to V2, all customers on V2 experience a latency until the pool has restarted.

Our application need to receive the subdomain in the url because we depend on it to connect to the corresponding database. Each customer has his own database.

It seems that IIS is not the solution for all bindings we have to manage.

Any tips ?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

After read posts, documentation and tryings, my conclusion was to use Azure Application Gateway and using different port for each version (website). All subdomains can be manage by the Gateway without impact on IIS, so no recycling.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add or remove bindings to IIS without recycling the application pool? If so, then you can try to set the `Disable Recyling for Configuation` Changes to `True`.

Open the IIS > select the Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Recycling > set the Disable Recyling for Configuation Changes to True.